# How to use Google's structured data content to display movie schedule?

Tags: google-search, google-rich-snippets, google-search-console

I'm developing a website for local cinema here in my city. 
I want to know how to register movie schedule to Google like the screenshot below that I taken from other cinema's website. It's pretty cool.

[image: cinemaxx]

My schedule consists of a movie list with each movie has an array of show time & date, eg:

```
AVENGERS THE MOVIE
   - 10/25/2017 13.30
   - 10/25/2017 15.30
   - ...
```

I read the Google's guide, but the closest that I can get is to create events [data-type](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events). Which I think is not what I want.

Can anyone help to with link or guide how to acomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for the [TV-movie (Google Docs)](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/tv-movie) type.

And to be specific the following object property:

> **releasedEvent.startDate**   (Date, recommended)
>
> - Original broadcast/theatrical release date of the work, in ISO 8601 format.